# tensorflow 2 for CUDA 9.0; Could not load dynamic library 'libcusolver.so.9.0'; undefined symbol: GOMP_critical_end;

Tags: tensorflow2.0, nvidia-docker

I have an Nvidia driver v:396, and I can't update it as another application running inside docker depends on it.

So, I used this repo https://github.com/SmileTM/Tensorflow2.X-GPU-CUDA9.0 to install tf2 inside docker container nvidia/cuda:9.0-cudnn7-devel

But when I install the tensorflow and try to run `tf.test.is_gpu_available()` I get the following output:

```
>>> tf.test.is_gpu_available()
WARNING:tensorflow:From <stdin>:1: is_gpu_available (from tensorflow.python.framework.test_util) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` instead.
2021-05-02 17:55:39.369149: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2021-05-02 17:55:40.073345: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:05:00.0 name: Quadro P4000 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.48GHz coreCount: 14 deviceMemorySize: 7.93GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 226.62GiB/s
2021-05-02 17:55:40.073783: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.9.0
2021-05-02 17:55:40.075887: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.9.0
2021-05-02 17:55:40.077755: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.9.0
2021-05-02 17:55:40.107478: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.9.0
2021-05-02 17:55:40.108647: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusolver.so.9.0'; dlerror: /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusolver.so.9.0: undefined symbol: GOMP_critical_end; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64
2021-05-02 17:55:40.110743: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.9.0
2021-05-02 17:55:40.116016: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2021-05-02 17:55:40.116046: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1592] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2021-05-02 17:55:40.384507: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1096] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-05-02 17:55:40.384578: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102]      0
2021-05-02 17:55:40.384595: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] 0:   N
False
```

Comment: Tensorflow 2 has all the library dependencies it needs hardcoded into it and delay loads everything itself. TF2 has no built-in support for CUDA 9. Whoever hacked it didn't get it right

Comment: So, you mean the wheels provided by the github repo is buggy? I got GPU available after some patch, but not sure if there will be some issue while training.

Answer (score 0):

```
import ctypes
ctypes.CDLL("libgomp.so.1", mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
```

Now, `tf.test.is_gpu_available()` returns `True`.